# download Crystal Reports for Visual Studio SP15 (13.0.15.1840)

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a need to download an old Crystal Reports for Visual Studio SP15 13.0.15.1840. Is this still available to download from somewhere?

Comment: Did you try using the SP32 download from SAP yet?  I haven't used VS since the 2012 release myself, but it looks like the newer service packs have more backwards compatibility than they used to have.  The SAP website indicates SP32 should cover VS 2022 and earlier versions back to the 2010 release.  If that doesn't work, you may need to contact SAP support for more help.

Answer (score -1):

Their latest link for runtime downloads
https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html